# How to show one thing on category and another thing on page 2 of the same category (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress

I want that the first page of my category will use some html theme and the second page and up (page 2,page 3...page 9999) will use other html theme.
(So that the main entrance for the category will be nice and pretty, and the next pages will be like the normal archive)

What is the right solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on your expertise in wordpress. If you are using a custom developed theme, the best thing would be to use different [page templates](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/) for each page. Page templates are quite simple way of customizing the look of a page completely different from another page.

If you dont have much development experience OR if you have already selected theme for your home page and another theme for your secondary pages then what you need is a plugin like [Multiple Themes](https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/). I haven't used it, so i cant say anything about it. But i think it might slow your site down a bit, so use it on staging site first.

**Update (After Discussion in comments):**
You should checkout wordpress template hierarchy. Its the way the files are called depending on each action. I am not actually understanding what you are trying to achieve but if you want to have separate page design for each category and single page design for archive then what you need to do is to create different files for each of your category and name them category-$slug.php (replace $slug with the slug of category) and then create a single archive.php.

**Basically here is the priority of the files are called on category and archive page request. It will start looking for the files from the top and skip them if they are not available until it finds the file thats available.**

1. category-slug.php
2. category-ID.php
3. category.php
4. archive.php
5. index.php

Comment: I created a page for each category, But the problem was that the url was the same as the category archive what cause some rewrite porblems..:\ I want to keep the url structure

Comment: Well sometimes url rewrite problems can be solved by simply visiting settings > permalink (then click on save)

Comment: try that. but the problem is that 
site.com/catname --> go to page
site.com/catname --> go to archive...

Comment: Are you sure you have 2 separate pages i.e category.php and archive.php?

Comment: yes. does site.com/catname/page/2 should get from the archive.php. and not the category.php?

Comment: No, it should work with category.php because it has higher priority. But just try copying the content of category.php to category-$slug.php   checkout the updated answer.